# join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'dict' -- in Django while making a form with Multi-Table inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a form for a model, that inherits from the Django auth.User class

I got this issue. Is there a better way to achieve it?

```
#models.py

class Teacher(User):
    #tutor = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_no = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.tutor.first_name, self.tutor.last_name)

#Forms.py
class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'contact_no', 'department')

#views.py
def new_teacher(request):
    form = TeacherForm()
    return render(request, {'form': form})
```

> Django Version:    2.2.3
> Exception Type:    TypeError

> Exception Value:
> join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'dict'

========================================================================

> The Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /account/newteacher/ Traceback > (most recent call last): File > "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", > line 34, in inner > response = get_response(request) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", > line 115, in _get_response > response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", > line 113, in _get_response > response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/accounts/views.py", > line 14, in new_teacher > return render(request, {'form': form}) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", > line 36, in render > content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) File > "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", > line 61, in render_to_string > template = get_template(template_name, using=using) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", > line 15, in get_template > return engine.get_template(template_name) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", > line 34, in get_template > return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self) File > "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", > line 143, in get_template > template, origin = self.find_template(template_name) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", > line 125, in find_template > template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", > line 18, in get_template > for origin in self.get_template_sources(template_name): File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py", > line 36, in get_template_sources > name = safe_join(template_dir, template_name) File "/home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", > line 32, in safe_join > final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths)) File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 94, in join > genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p) File "/usr/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 149, in _check_arg_types > (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'dict' [06/Aug/2019 08:41:05] "GET > /account/newteacher/ HTTP/1.1" 500 120952
```

Comment: Please share the traceback or the actual code producing the error

Comment: you mean the complete code?

Comment: The traceback you are getting from the error is a start

Comment: Do not make your model both inherit from AND have a foreign key to `User` - it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @SiddhanthKasat: no, the *traceback*: https://realpython.com/python-traceback/

Comment: I am sorry but for dumb formatting of the post but I am new around here

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers
I commented it out but its still not working

Comment: @Batman I'm not saying this would fix your issue (which is indeed totally unrelated), just that it doesn't make sense and is certainly not what you want.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers
Yeah, I get it, it makes sense.
what can I do about the problem, any suggestions?

Comment: @Batman I can only make an educated guess since I know zilch about your project, but from what I see it seems you just want `Teacher`  to be a plain model (inheriting from `models.Model`) with a one-to-one relationship on ` User` (assuming that not all your users are teachers).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here:

> /home/zed/PycharmProjects/untitledisbesttitle/accounts/views.py", > line 14, in new_teacher 
>   return render(request, {'form': form})

`render()` second argument is supposed to be the (relative) template path:

```
return render(request, "yourapp/yourtemplate.html", {'form': form})
```

The traceback that goes with the error message is the very first thing to check to find out where an exception occurs.

Comment: ohhh!! That was a noob move from me, Thanks a ton!

Comment: another quick one, How do I make the name fields mandatory?
for some reason they arent right now

Comment: They aren't in the `User` model definition. But you don't wan't your model to inherit from `User` anyway.

Comment: I have different users that have common fields from user, lets say teacher students etc, they all have fname, lname, username
So, I made their different models with extra fields and kept the base model as User model
(Just so that I dont have to set custom validation for each one of them)

Comment: from a design POV, "teacher", "student" etc are not User subtypes but roles a User can have (and technically the same user could be both teaching some discipline and studying another one - that's not uncommon in universities, engineering schools etc), so inheritance is not the proper design here. Also, from a technical POV, using concrete inheritance means that creating a `Teacher` or `Student` record will __not__ create the matching `User` record, and neither `Teacher`  nor `Student` models will be used for auth, so this "solution" doesn't work at the implementation level either.

Comment: so if inheritance is not a good option here, what do you suggest ? how so=hould this be implemented?

Comment: With a one to one relationship between your "role" models (Student, Teacher etc) and User - which you already have FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not passing one argument `request`

```
template_name = 'edx_sysadmin/gitlogs.html'
context = {'data': 'value'}
return render(request, self.template_name, context)


# earlier was missing `request` like
# return render(self.template_name, context)
```

But you need to explore your traceback logs to see the route cause of the error by the help of checking to find out where an exception occurs.